# .PNG's not displaying if user clicks any picture other than first [opera]

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Opera seems to be the only browser that when any of my images other images than the top first one on the page are clicked, then the next/previous buttons don't show up, but the user can still go forward/backward; the buttons seem to reappear for a split second after the sides of the image are clicked. In this manner, if they user scrolls through the images, sometimes one of the next/previous buttons appear in a fixed position over the image right from the start (normally they don't appear unless the user hovers to either side of the image). Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'group')
        .fancybox({
            padding: 0,
            openSpeed: "fast",
            closeSpeed: "fast",
            nextSpeed: "normal",
            prevSpeed: "normal",
            helpers: { 
                overlay: { 
                    css: {
                        'background' : '#000000',
                        'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)',
                        /*'background' : '#000000',*/
                        /*'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=60)',*/
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: make sure you don't use global css declarations like `a {background: #ccc;}` or `a:hover {background: #ccc;}` ... use specificity instead like `#myContainer a {background: #ccc;}` .... otherwise share a link because I don't think there is any conflict with opera. Does this http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/ fail in opera as you describe? what version? works fine for me in v12.02

Comment: @JFK jsfiddle works, and I'm using latest version of Opera- http://75.83.61.208/claire/portfolio/ladies.html

Comment: your link doesn't seem to work

Comment: mmmm, sorry but still not working

Comment: Hmm I guess my computer needs to be running for you to see it? Try it again, I'll be here for the next 5 hours or so. If it doesn't work I'll try and find another way to show you the WIP so you can try it in Opera